# C# (xamarin project) not able to find path to the file

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this problem when I'm trying to read JSON file (or any file): *It's not able to find that file.* I try everything, even the absolute path (error almost same - DirectoryNotFound)

[image]

**This is structure of mine code:**

[image]

**And this is code:**

```
private void LoadJson()
{
    
    using (var r = new StreamReader("quizQuestions.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Questions>>(json);
    }
}
```

I I even try to use *Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()* but it's returning : **/** -> only this character. I don't know where is a mistake or if I forgot to set something. I try to find answers everywhere but I was not able to find anything with this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Build Action of the file is set as `Content` or as an `Asset` and give this a try.

```
private void LoadJson()
{
    AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
    using (var r = new StreamReader(assets.Open ("quizQuestions.json")))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Questions>>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is response: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.companyname.quizApp/files/.local/share/quizQuestions.json"

Comment: This is written as a comment. If it is intended as such, please post is as such, not as an answer. Else please explain what you are suggesting.

Comment: I have improved my 'answer' .. I think this might get us there.

Comment: Okay, it seems that it's working. 
Before I had method LoadJson in _MainPage.xaml.cs_  -> so I move it to the _MainActivity.cs_ but instead of creating method LoadJson I put it into _MessagingCenter.Subscribe_ in _protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)_ and then in _MainPage.xaml.cs_ I call _MessagingCenter.Send_  ...and this is working... but I don't know If it's correct approach :D

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the file as `Embedded Resource` and then access it like this:

```
public static Stream GetEmbeddedResourceStream(Assembly assembly, string resourceFileName)
{
    var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    var resourcePaths = resourceNames
            .Where(x => x.EndsWith(resourceFileName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();

    if (resourcePaths.Any() && resourcePaths.Count() == 1)
    {
        return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePaths.Single());
    }
    return null; // or throw Exception
}

private void LoadJson()
{
    Assembly assembly = GetAssemblyContainingTheJson();
    using (var r = GetEmbeddedResourceStream(assembly, "quizQuestions.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Questions>>(json);
    }
}
```